# Spring Boot Token Authorization with Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application where I use some services from docker. The authorization is implemented on a service in docker, but I don't know " how to connect to it " .

When I try to make calls, I get the error:

```
UNAUTHENTICATED: Authentication failed
```

These are the call credentials:

```
callCredentials = CallCredentialsHelper.basicAuth("user", "pass");
callCredentials = CallCredentialsHelper.bearerAuth("name-of-the-token");
```

I have the username, password and token name for it. What are the steps regarding this problem?

Comment: It depends what service do you have in docker, but you should have some address and to know how to generate the request to this service, If it is rest or it is soap or even something else

Comment: show your code change the password and username by some dummy value to share it with us to know better what are you doing

Comment: How I can find if it's rest? I use just docker-compose for running the services.

Comment: but what is running this docker?

Comment: I edited my question. I run it in command line.